# Get index fields with conditions?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all fields from index like mappings (localhost:9200/indx/_mapping/), but with condition or term.

Is it possible? please help.

- _mapping sends all fields (there are more than 6000 parameters), I need only from one section.
- tried meta-field "_field_names" in an aggs part, but it has been deprecated

I trying to create some products page, there you can select needed section and get list of parameters to filter out products.

For example, for cables it will be material, for chips power, etc.

If I set name of field manually, I get needed values for that parameter, but i need to get list of parameters dynamically and by condition.

Example query:

```
{
"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"12758","fields":["desq^1","title^2","partnum^3","partnumrs^4"],"type":"best_fields","operator":"or","fuzziness":1}},{"multi_match":{"query":"12758","fields":["desq^1","title^2","partnum^3","partnumrs^4"],"type":"phrase_prefix","operator":"or"}}],"minimum_should_match":"1"}}]}}]}},
"highlight":{"pre_tags":["<mark>"],"post_tags":["</mark>"],"fields":{"desq":{},"title":{},"partnum":{},"partnumrs":{}}},
"aggs":{
  "power.keyword":{"terms":{"field":"power.keyword","size":30,"order":{"_count":"desc"},"missing":"N/A"}},
  "brand.keyword":{"terms":{"field":"brand.keyword","size":30,"order":{"_count":"desc"},"missing":"N/A"}}},
"_source":{"includes":["*"],"excludes":[]},"from":0,"size":8
}
```

Alternative: Val's comment, manually generate meta index. Query all documents for needed section by conditions, get unique fields of the documents, save the fields to meta index for each section. When a client open section i can get the filds list and query aggregation for them.

Comment: Maybe show what you've tried so far

Comment: Val, "_field_names" depricated, "_mapping" gets ALL 6000 params.
Is there a method to get fields list by condition?

Comment: No, not that I know of, but with some external means (using `jq`, `awk` et al) you might be able to achieve what you want. Or index your mapping document into a meta index with one document per field and you might be able to query it.

Comment: Reading elastic documentation, checking many stackoverflow answers, trying all finded cURL examples. I just don't know what to find, is that method exist?

Comment: You might want to check the [Field capabilities API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-field-caps.html)

Comment: curl with grep or to file and open with notepad++ or smthng, 6000 is ok (it could be 6 millions :))

Comment: Val, cheked "field capabilities API", it's still get all fields, but with extra info. But thank you, i'll use it in an another task.

Comment: Dejan Marić, yes, 6000 ok, but this fields need to be added to another query in aggs section for aggregation on a millions of documents, that has not worked.